# Varghidpolis never uses Apoptosis, why?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

I'm trying to get Apoptosis for the Enemy Skill materia.

Late game spoilers:

> I'm at the Combat Simulator in the Shinra building, which seems purpose built to give you a second chance at a lot of the enemy skills. I had given up on the skill by Ch 14 because I was eventually way overleveled for the ones in the collapsed tunnel, but now it's available again though I imagine for the last time.

Is there a way to provoke the AI into using the skill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apoptosis is learned as Self-Destruct, so if you’ve gotten that you’re good. There’s only 4: Algrid Aura, Soul Siphon, Self-Destruct, and Bad Breath.